# Get All Items from HTML5 FormData Object - HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, form-data

I have been working with the HTML5 FormData object and I can't seem to figure out how to find what data it holds. I need to access it for debugging purposes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Zoo.png)

There are functions like

```
FormData::get([name]);
```

but I don't know the names. It would be nice to have something like the following:

```
FormData::dumpData();
```

What is a good way to view all of the data in a FormData object?

**Update**

Here is an example of the FormData object:

[image]

Comment: console.log(FormData)  ??

Comment: I've been trying to look through the output from this; I can't seem to find the form's data.

Comment: can you edit your post to show the output of that

Comment: From what I understand, the FormData object is meant to be used for nothing more than submit-time submission; it's possible that upon its construction, it doesn't actually save the correct information to output individual key/values. You can append to it, but as shown in your example, it doesn't have a "get" function. What's the use case where you need its values?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking the same, @Katana314. I am using it for AJAX file uploading. I think I will just have to use the form itself to validate the file inputs. Like you said, it is probably simply for the raw data and doesn't have constructs like what I am looking for.

Answer (score 7):

All the functions for `FormData` aren't available in all browsers by default. However, you can enable them in some. Checkout the docs for [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility).

In Chrome, you'll be able to enable full access to these functions by enabling **Enable experimental Web Platform feature** under the browser flags section. Navigate to `chrome://flags/` in the browser to find this option.

Once you've enable this feature and reloaded, you should be able to run the following to view all your `FormData`, data:

```
var formData    = new FormData(this);
var formKeys    = formData.keys();
var formEntries = formData.entries();

do {
  console.log(formEntries.next().value);
} while (!formKeys.next().done)
```

Granted, there are probably better ways to iterate over this data structure, although  it is certainly one way to view all the K/V pairs in your `FormData` object dynamically.

Comment: > TypeError: formData.keys is not a function.