# Why a FormData is still empty even after an append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

I'm trying to send an ajax form to a controller, but the data attribute arrive empty to the controller, this is my code:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('asd', 123);
console.log(fd);
var idServicio = $("#id-building-form-add-new-stand").val();
var idEdificio = $("#id-service-form-add-new-stand").val();
var piso = $("#id-floor-form-add-new-stand").val();
var idJornada = $("#id-jornada-form-add-new-stand").val();
fd.append("idServicio", idServicio);
fd.append("idEdificio", idEdificio);
fd.append("piso", piso);
fd.append("idJornada", idJornada);
fd.append("jsonStand", JSON.stringify(jsonStand));
fd.append("accion", "1");

console.log(fd);
```

after I put my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    url: epStand,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: fd,
    success: function (statusM) {
        //toggleModalCargando();
        var data = JSON.parse(statusM);
        if (data.status === 1) {
            console.log("éxito");
            $.unblockUI();
        } else {
            if (data.status === 0) {
                $.unblockUI();
                throwAlert(data.dataObject[0].message, "error");
            } else {
                $.unblockUI();
                throwAlert(data.descripcion, "error");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

However the fd variable is empty in all my logs console and of course in the controller.

Comment: This is normal that in console it is empty, (that's not [how you retrieve stored data in FormData from js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28906435/3702797)), but it should not be empty in your controller/

Comment: Try `console.log(fd.entries());`

Comment: It is still empty